# iOS In-App subscriptions : Test User Purchase History

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have successfully gotten all the in-app purchase logic to work. I created a test user in itunesconnect.apple.com and made a test purchase (a 1 month auto renewing subscription) on a real device with that test user.

Where is the web interface to see a list of all the active subscriptions? That is, I want to create several test users and see what it's going to be like when we get to production. I need a way to view how many total active subscriptions we have, which users are about to expire, projected revenue for the month. i.e. everything a business person would want to see in a nice report. I looked all over itunesconnect and didn't see this anywhere. Does it exist?

Comment: So, it means you want the remaining time of the purchased item ? that is about to renew. right ? or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question and you want the same as i asked in comment then you should see this link. you will get the idea from this link.

[Click Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

and in this link you should check this out.

```
- (int)daysRemainingOnSubscription {
//1
NSDate *expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                          objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];

//2
NSTimeInterval timeInt = [expirationDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];

//3
int days = timeInt / 60 / 60 / 24;

//4
if (days > 0) {
    return days;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

and also this methods too

```
- (NSDate *)getExpirationDateForMonths:(int)months;
- (NSString *)getExpirationDateString
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i was hoping for something on itunesconnect.apple.com already showing a nice report for all test users.  Not something I had to write new code for.